# Update the Value of a Per-Session Custom Dimension Once Set?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm a writing a proof of concept involving GA Core Reporting API integration and would like to know if it's possible, after creation via:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-X');
ga('send', 'pageview', {
    'dimension1': '[Uid]'
    'dimension2': ''
});
```

... to retrieve a page view by its unique identifier (which could be another dimension, as above) and update another of the dimensions. For example, decisioning data obtained at a later date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. It 's not possible in realtime because the realtime API does not expose custom dimensions, and it's probably not possible via data imports (at least in the standard version of GA) because data imports do not change data retroactively (I think Premium has now a feature to apply data retroactively, but I'm not at all sure those data sets can be retrieved via the API. I haven't tested that, though, so maybe someone with more experience can weigh in).

Plus you are talking about a session based dimension. A session based dimension cannot identify a single page, since it belongs to a session. You'd need a hit based dimension to uniquely identify a page (actually you have one by default since Urls should be unique).

Comment: That's right - my OP was probably incorrectly worded here - this is all established as a page view, but only ever sent once per session so it will be unique. But as you say, doesn't look likely on being able to retrospectively update the value.